# How do you simplify this result?

Tags: probability, self-study

I am looking at this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1223462/hypothesis-test-between-two-normal-distributions).  I get this part:

$$\frac{1}{2^n(2\pi)^{n/2}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{8}\sum_{i=1}^nt_i^2\right)<\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^nt_i^2\right)$$

However, I have trouble simplifying down to the final result.  Can someone help?

Comment: **This clearly is not generally true.**  One example is the case $n=0,$ for which the vacuous sums are (by definition) zero, whence it asserts $1 = \exp(0) \lt \exp(0) = 1,$ which is false. As a less trivial counterexample consider the case $n=1$ and write $z=t_1^2/8.$ The inequality becomes $$\frac{1}{2}\exp(-z) \lt \exp(-4z).$$ Taking $z\gt (\log 2)/3$ gives a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

OK, took a while with my rusty exponential arithmetic:

$\frac{1}{2^n(\sqrt{2\pi})^n}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2\cdot 2^2}\sum_{i=1}^nt_i^2\right)<\frac{1}{1^n(\sqrt{2\pi})^n}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2\cdot 1^2}\sum_{i=1}^nt_i^2\right)$

$\Leftrightarrow\exp\left(-\frac{1}{8}\sum_{i=1}^nt_i^2\right)<2^n\cdot\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^nt_i^2\right)$

$\Leftrightarrow\exp\left(-\frac{1}{8}\sum_{i=1}^nt_i^2+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^nt_i^2\right)<2^n\cdot\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^nt_i^2+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^nt_i^2\right)$

$\Leftrightarrow\exp\left(\frac{3}{8}\sum_{i=1}^nt_i^2\right)<2^n\cdot 1$

$\Leftrightarrow\frac{3}{8}\sum_{i=1}^nt_i^2<\ln(2^n)+0$

$\Leftrightarrow\frac{3}{8}\sum_{i=1}^nt_i^2<n\ln(2)$

$\Leftrightarrow\frac{3}{8n\ln(2)}\sum_{i=1}^nt_i^2<1$

Comment: In the middle you seem to claim $1=0.$

Comment: My bad.  It's fixed.